# how to get first element without any delay and delay from the second element?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

```
 fun initScreenSaver(){
       Observable.fromCallable({GetScreenSaverUrlInteractor().execute() })
               .flatMapIterable{ urls-> urls }
               .zipWith(Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), { item, interval -> item })
               .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
               .subscribe(object : Subscriber<String>(){
                   override fun onNext(url: String?) {
                      view.loadImage(url)
                   }

                   override fun onCompleted() {
                       initScreenSaver()
                   }

                   override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                       TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                   }

               })
   }
```

here I have tried to get the elements in a delay of 10 second and loading in ImageView.But the first element should appear instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable.interval()` has a signature:

```
Observable<Long> interval(long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
```

You can use it like this:

```
Observable.interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

**UPD**

```
Observable.just ( listOf("Elem1", "Elem2", "Elem3", "Elem4") )
    .flatMapIterable{ urls -> urls }
    .zipWith<Long, String>(Observable.interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), BiFunction { t1, t2 ->  t1})
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnSubscribe { Log.d("DEBUG", "Start emitting")}
    .subscribe{Log.d("DEBUG", "item: $it")}
```

Output:

```
03-28 10:06:48.956 17086-17086/com.example.app D/DEBUG: Start emitting
03-28 10:06:49.633 17086-17086/com.example.app D/DEBUG: item: Elem1
03-28 10:06:58.957 17086-17086/com.example.app D/DEBUG: item: Elem2
03-28 10:07:08.957 17086-17086/com.example.app D/DEBUG: item: Elem3
03-28 10:07:18.957 17086-17086/com.example.app D/DEBUG: item: Elem4
```

Comment: I just checked, it should work. What `GetScreenSaverUrlInteractor().execute()`  returns?

Comment: String arrayList

Comment: Please see UPD. What doesn't work exactly in your snippet? Does your observable emits first item after 10 seconds? I'm using rxjava2, but I doubt if it is the reason.

Comment: your code is working for me but on complete again I want to do the same task of showing the url again in an endless loop

Comment: You should post it as separate question, initial topic has nothing about infinite loop.